# Java applet to implement Digital signature using smart card

Tags: java, browser, applet, digital-signature, pkcs#11

How to sign a post(any document or text) in browser using smart card. 
What I have investigated so far:

ActiveX - IE only
**Silverlight** - no access to certificates at all and as a plugin faces the same limitations as Java

**Browser specific extensions**; For example Firefox up until version 33 used to have window.crypto.signText but not anymore

**local applications installed on the client** - not easy to install, support, develop and update for several OS and their different versions.

**Web Cryptography** - "only basic cryptographic functions", no certificates support
I ran out of ideas. 
All suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

i tried a java applet the code is here below.                                            main class: Smartcard applet.java    public class SmartCardSignerApplet extends Applet {

```
private static final String FILE_NAME_FIELD_PARAM = "fileNameField";
private static final String CERT_CHAIN_FIELD_PARAM = "certificationChainField";
private static final String SIGNATURE_FIELD_PARAM = "signatureField";
private static final String SIGN_BUTTON_CAPTION_PARAM = "signButtonCaption";

private static final String PKCS11_KEYSTORE_TYPE = "PKCS11";
private static final String X509_CERTIFICATE_TYPE = "X.509";
private static final String CERTIFICATION_CHAIN_ENCODING = "PkiPath";
private static final String DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_NAME = "SHA1withRSA";
private static final String SUN_PKCS11_PROVIDER_CLASS = "sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11";

private Button mSignButton;   //initialises applet public void init() {
    String signButtonCaption = this.getParameter(SIGN_BUTTON_CAPTION_PARAM);
    mSignButton = new Button(signButtonCaption);
    mSignButton.setLocation(0, 0);
    Dimension appletSize = this.getSize();
    mSignButton.setSize(appletSize);
    mSignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            signSelectedFile();
        }
    });
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.add(mSignButton);
}    \\   signing the file private void signSelectedFile() {
    try {
        // Get the file name to be signed from the form in the HTML document
        JSObject browserWindow = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        JSObject mainForm = (JSObject) browserWindow.eval("document.forms[0]");
        String fileNameFieldName = this.getParameter(FILE_NAME_FIELD_PARAM);
        JSObject fileNameField = (JSObject) mainForm.getMember(fileNameFieldName);
        String fileName = (String) fileNameField.getMember("value");

        // Perform the actual file signing
        CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 signingResult = signFile(fileName);
        if (signingResult != null) {
            // Document  signed. Fill the certificate and signature fields
            String certChainFieldName = this.getParameter(CERT_CHAIN_FIELD_PARAM);
            JSObject certChainField = (JSObject) mainForm.getMember(certChainFieldName);
            certChainField.setMember("value", signingResult.mCertificationChain);
            String signatureFieldName = this.getParameter(SIGNATURE_FIELD_PARAM);
            JSObject signatureField = (JSObject) mainForm.getMember(signatureFieldName);
            signatureField.setMember("value", signingResult.mSignature);
        } else {
            // User canceled signing
        }
    }
    catch (DocumentSignException dse) {
        // Document signing failed. Display error message
        String errorMessage = dse.getMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, errorMessage);
    }
    catch (SecurityException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Unable to access the local file system.\n" +
            "This applet should be started with full security permissions.\n" +
            "Please accept to trust this applet when the Java Plug-In ask you.");
    }
    catch (JSException jse) {
        jse.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Unable to access some of the fields of the\n" +
            "HTML form. Please check the applet parameters.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

private CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 signFile(String aFileName)
    throws DocumentSignException {

```
    // Load the file for signing
    byte[] documentToSign = null;
    try {
        documentToSign = readFileInByteArray(aFileName);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        String errorMessage = "Can not read the file for signing " + aFileName + ".";
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage, ioex);
    }

    // Show a dialog for choosing PKCS#11 implementation library and smart card PIN
    PKCS11LibraryFileAndPINCodeDialog pkcs11Dialog =
        new PKCS11LibraryFileAndPINCodeDialog();
    boolean dialogConfirmed;
    try {
        dialogConfirmed = pkcs11Dialog.run();
    } finally {
        pkcs11Dialog.dispose();
    }

    if (dialogConfirmed) {
        String oldButtonLabel = mSignButton.getLabel();
        mSignButton.setLabel("Working...");
        mSignButton.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            String pkcs11LibraryFileName = pkcs11Dialog.getLibraryFileName();
            String pinCode = pkcs11Dialog.getSmartCardPINCode();

            // Do the actual signing of the document with the smart card
            CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 signingResult =
                signDocument(documentToSign, pkcs11LibraryFileName, pinCode);
            return signingResult;
        } finally {
            mSignButton.setLabel(oldButtonLabel);
            mSignButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

private CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 signDocument(
    byte[] aDocumentToSign, String aPkcs11LibraryFileName, String aPinCode)
throws DocumentSignException {
    if (aPkcs11LibraryFileName.length() == 0) {
        String errorMessage = "It is mandatory to choose a PCKS#11 native " +
            "implementation library for for smart card (.dll or .so file)!";
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage);
    }

    // Load the keystore from the smart card using the specified PIN code
    KeyStore userKeyStore = null;
    try {
        userKeyStore = loadKeyStoreFromSmartCard(aPkcs11LibraryFileName, aPinCode);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String errorMessage = "Can not read the keystore from the smart card.\n" +
            "Possible reasons:\n" +
            " - The smart card reader in not connected.\n" +
            " - The smart card is not inserted.\n" +
            " - The PKCS#11 implementation library is invalid.\n" +
            " - The PIN for the smart card is incorrect.\n" +
            "Problem details: " + ex.getMessage();
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage, ex);
    }

    // Get the private key and its certification chain from the keystore
    PrivateKeyAndCertChain privateKeyAndCertChain = null;
    try {
        privateKeyAndCertChain =
            getPrivateKeyAndCertChain(userKeyStore);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException gsex) {
        String errorMessage = "Can not extract the private key and " +
            "certificate from the smart card. Reason: " + gsex.getMessage();
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage, gsex);
    }

    // Check if the private key is available
    PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyAndCertChain.mPrivateKey;
    if (privateKey == null) {
        String errorMessage = "Can not find the private key on the smart card.";
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage);
    }

    // Check if X.509 certification chain is available
    Certificate[] certChain = privateKeyAndCertChain.mCertificationChain;
    if (certChain == null) {
        String errorMessage = "Can not find the certificate on the smart card.";
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage);
    }

    // Create the result object
    CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 signingResult =
        new CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64();

    // Save X.509 certification chain in the result encoded in Base64
    try {
        signingResult.mCertificationChain = encodeX509CertChainToBase64(certChain);
    }
    catch (CertificateException cee) {
        String errorMessage = "Invalid certificate on the smart card.";
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage);
    }

    // Calculate the digital signature of the file,
    // encode it in Base64 and save it in the result
    try {
        byte[] digitalSignature = signDocument(aDocumentToSign, privateKey);
        signingResult.mSignature = Base64Utils.base64Encode(digitalSignature);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException gsex) {
        String errorMessage = "File signing failed.\n" +
            "Problem details: " + gsex.getMessage();
        throw new DocumentSignException(errorMessage, gsex);
    }

    return signingResult;
}

/**
 * Loads the keystore from the smart card using its PKCS#11 implementation
 * library and the Sun PKCS#11 security provider. The PIN code for accessing
 * the smart card is required.
 */
private KeyStore loadKeyStoreFromSmartCard(String aPKCS11LibraryFileName,
    String aSmartCardPIN)
throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    // First configure the Sun PKCS#11 provider. It requires a stream (or file)
    // containing the configuration parameters - "name" and "library".
    String pkcs11ConfigSettings =
        "name = SmartCard\n" + "library = " + aPKCS11LibraryFileName;
    byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);

    // Instantiate the provider dynamically with Java reflection
    try {
        Class sunPkcs11Class = Class.forName(SUN_PKCS11_PROVIDER_CLASS);
        Constructor pkcs11Constr = sunPkcs11Class.getConstructor(
            java.io.InputStream.class);
        Provider pkcs11Provider = (Provider) pkcs11Constr.newInstance(confStream);
        Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new KeyStoreException("Can initialize Sun PKCS#11 security " +
            "provider. Reason: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    // Read the keystore form the smart card
    char[] pin = aSmartCardPIN.toCharArray();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(PKCS11_KEYSTORE_TYPE);
    keyStore.load(null, pin);
    return keyStore;
}

/**
 * @return private key and certification chain corresponding to it, extracted from
 * given keystore. The keystore is considered to have only one entry that contains
 * both certification chain and its corresponding private key. If the keystore has
 * no entries, an exception is thrown.
 */
private PrivateKeyAndCertChain getPrivateKeyAndCertChain(
    KeyStore aKeyStore)
throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Enumeration aliasesEnum = aKeyStore.aliases();
    if (aliasesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = (String)aliasesEnum.nextElement();
        Certificate[] certificationChain = aKeyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) aKeyStore.getKey(alias, null);
        PrivateKeyAndCertChain result = new PrivateKeyAndCertChain();
        result.mPrivateKey = privateKey;
        result.mCertificationChain = certificationChain;
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new KeyStoreException("The keystore is empty!");
    }
}

/**
 * @return Base64-encoded ASN.1 DER representation of given X.509 certification
 * chain.
 */
private String encodeX509CertChainToBase64(Certificate[] aCertificationChain)
throws CertificateException {
    List certList = Arrays.asList(aCertificationChain);
    CertificateFactory certFactory =
        CertificateFactory.getInstance(X509_CERTIFICATE_TYPE);
    CertPath certPath = certFactory.generateCertPath(certList);
    byte[] certPathEncoded = certPath.getEncoded(CERTIFICATION_CHAIN_ENCODING);
    String base64encodedCertChain = Base64Utils.base64Encode(certPathEncoded);
    return base64encodedCertChain;
}

/**
 * Reads the specified file into a byte array.
 */
private byte[] readFileInByteArray(String aFileName)
throws IOException {
    File file = new File(aFileName);
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        int fileSize = (int) file.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesRead < fileSize) {
            bytesRead += fileStream.read(data, bytesRead, fileSize-bytesRead);
        }
        return data;
    }
    finally {
        fileStream.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Signs given document with a given private key.
 */
private byte[] signDocument(byte[] aDocument, PrivateKey aPrivateKey)
throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Signature signatureAlgorithm =
        Signature.getInstance(DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_NAME);
    signatureAlgorithm.initSign(aPrivateKey);
    signatureAlgorithm.update(aDocument);
    byte[] digitalSignature = signatureAlgorithm.sign();
    return digitalSignature;
}

/**
 * Data structure that holds a pair of private key and
 * certification chain corresponding to this private key.
 */
static class PrivateKeyAndCertChain {
    public PrivateKey mPrivateKey;
    public Certificate[] mCertificationChain;
}

/**
 * Data structure that holds a pair of Base64-encoded
 * certification chain and digital signature.
 */
static class CertificationChainAndSignatureBase64 {
    public String mCertificationChain = null;
    public String mSignature = null;
}

/**
 * Exception class used for document signing errors.
 */
static class DocumentSignException extends Exception {
    public DocumentSignException(String aMessage) {
        super(aMessage);
    }

    public DocumentSignException(String aMessage, Throwable aCause) {
        super(aMessage, aCause);
    }
}
```

}   While i run the applet i get a message for ckr operations not found  . any help?

Comment: Indeed so far the Java applet is the only way to go. And what your actual question is?

Comment: applet with self signed certificates are restricted,so i placed the url in the exception list of java control manager. But while deployment, it may be a problem. Can we go for any other way?

Comment: you need to get a proper certificate to sign the applet. Don't use self-signed certificates.